# TFS Build 2015 MultiConfiguration - How to add common steps after all builds complete?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

With MultiConfiguration option, TFS Build can start several sub-builds in parallel with different parameters. How can I add a step after all those builds are successfully completed?

Specifically, I want to add a step that will put a label on changeset that was built and increment product version in source control.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't. Multi-configuration just executes all of the same steps N times, one for each combination of parameters.

Your best bet at the moment is to make whatever post-build action you create "thread"-safe and idempotent so that it can safely be run multiple times.